# How to increase the speed of omnet++ simulation for veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am running veins simulation with 512 Cars and 1 RSU. Simulation is really slow.

```
**Event #5553920 t=5.2235743222 Elapse:434.0.39s (12h 03m) 26% completed
Speed: ev/sec=136.352 simsec/sec=4.46673e-05 ev/simsec=3.0526e+06
Messages: created: 4592846 present: 1473 in FES: 456
```

I understand that veins FAQ mentions using Release mode.

> To create a release mode command line build, set the environment variable 'MODE=release'. Binaries should now be in 'out/gcc-release' -- if they are not, something went wrong.

Where do I set this environment variable?

I set MODE=release inside omnet++ GUI at the following path :

omnetpp.ini -> Run as -> Run configurations -> Environment tab -> Variable = MODE and Value = release

Is this the right way? I didn't notice any change in simulation speed.

Also where do I find the binaries to verify that they are now in 'out/gcc-release?

1
I am writing here because I don't have 50 reputation points to comment above.

OMNeT++ 5.1.1;veins 4.6;sumo 0.30.0

My computer specs are : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U @ 2.5GHz x 4 with 8 GB of RAM.

I have dual boot Linux 18.04 installed along with Windows 10. I have a virtual box installed inside Linux 18.04 which has Linux 16.04 image. Linux 16.04 is the environment for omnet++, veins, sumo.

Linux 18.04 has 64 GB of disk space.

VM-Linux 16.04 has 33 GB of disk space. System setting: Base Memory - 4 GB, Processor - 1 CPU. Display setting: Video memory - 128 MB

Comment: `136 ev/sec` sounds really low. Which versions of OMNeT++ (e.g., "5.4.1"), SUMO (e.g., "0.32.0"), and Veins (e.g., "4.7.1") are you using? What kind of computer (e.g. "Intel i7-2600 @ 3.40GHz with 16 GB of RAM") are you using? Which operating system (e.g., "Windows 10") are you using? If you run the Veins tutorial simulation (in `examples/veins`) of a fresh download of Veins in Cmdenv mode, how many `ev/sec` are you getting?

Comment: OMNeT++ 5.1.1;veins 4.6;sumo 0.30.0
My computer specs are : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U @ 2.5GHz x 4 with 8 GB of RAM. I have dual boot Linux 18.04 installed along with Windows 10. I have a virtual box installed inside Linux 18.04 which has Linux 16.04 image. Linux 16.04 is the environment for omnet++, veins, sumo. Linux 18.04 has 64 GB of disk space. VM-Linux 16.04 has 33 GB of disk space. System setting: Base Memory - 4 GB, Processor - 1 CPU. Display setting: Video memory - 128 MB

Answer (score 0):

Maybe having the OMNeT++ IDE open stresses your (virtual) machine out too much.

The easiest way of running fast Veins simulations is to compile them in `release` mode and to run them in `Cmdenv`. This can be done entirely from the command line, as follows.

First, if you are unsure how to execute your simulation on the command line: you can learn the required commands by launching your simulation from the OMNeT++ IDE and closely watching the first lines appearing in the Console view. Such commands typically start with `opp_run` or with the name of your simulation. For running your simulation in command line mode, all you have to do is to substitute `-u Cmdenv` for any other `-u` option the IDE might have used for launching, or to append `-u Cmdenv` if no `-u` parameter was present.

Open a command line and go to the directory that contains your Veins download. This is the directory that contains the `README.txt` of Veins.

> If you are using Linux, there are a number of good tutorials for how to open and use the command line online, e.g., https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/command-line-for-beginners. You might also be able to directly open a command line in the desired directory by navigating to this directory in your file manager, right clicking on empty space, and selecting something like "open terminal here":
>
> [image: "Open in Terminal" function of Nautilus]

Run `./configure` followed by `make MODE=release`. If you are using Veins 5.0, a simple `make` will also suffice.

Navigate to the directory of the simulation you want to run and execute the command you figured out earlier (remembering to use `-u Cmdenv`).

[image: Sample Screenshot for running Veins simulation in command line mode]

Comment: Thank you for this insight @Christoph Sommer.
When I move the veins directory and execute `./configure`, I receive the following error : `user@user-VirtualBox:~/simulte_veins/veins-veins-4.6$ ./configure
env: ‘opp_makemake’: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./configure", line 44, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call(['env', 'opp_makemake'] + makemake_flags, cwd='src')`

Comment: My guess is that you did not add OMNeT++ to your path or did not execute the setenv script of OMNeT++.

Comment: I have run the `. setenv` again and verified that `~/.bashrc` includes the omnetpp bin path. Still ./configure gives the same error. This is my directory organisation : /home/user/omnetpp ;/home/user/inet ; /home/user/simulte_veins/veins; /home/user/simulte_veins/simulte ; Does this needs reorganising or is it something else?

Comment: Also I verified if my cmdenv is setup correctly by running one of the sample omnet++ examples under sample folder and `./fifo -u Cmdenv -c Fifo1` works fine on command line.

Comment: I probably cannot be of help then. I have no idea what can lead to you being able to run opp_makemake, but a script you are running not being able to do the same thing. Sorry.

Comment: I went through my `~/.bashrc` file again and found a syntax error. Now I can build successfully run `./configure`. Thanks for the help @Christoph Sommer.
The simulation speed has relatively improved than before.